# Splitting a string in Make rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to split a string with colon separated values in Make target.

When i try to split the string in a target recipe using for loop, eval, shell i get the blank values. Where as when i do use the shell command to split the string outside the target result is positive.

Can any one help me fixing the target recipe.

Below is the snippet.

```
notebooks=new:e7e45d89-94cc-4783-86c5-2236d9904a24 test:2af1d689-98c3-48f2-984d-2ea21c5135dd
j=new:e7e45d89-94cc-4783-86c5-2236d9904a24
f1=$(shell echo $j | cut -d: -f 1)
test1:
    @for i in $(notebooks); \
    do \
        $(eval f=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 1))  \
        $(eval fid=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 2)) \
        echo $(f) $(fid) $(f1) ;\
    done
```

Output is

```
new
new
```

Whereas desired output is

```
new e7e45d89-94cc-4783-86c5-2236d9904a24 new 
test 2af1d689-98c3-48f2-984d-2ea21c5135dd new
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the most common confusion about makefiles it seems: the distinction between the *recipe* which is written in shell syntax, and make constructs.

The way make works is that *ALL* make constructs (variables and functions) in the recipe are first evaluated by make, then the resulting expanded string is passed to the shell and the shell executes it.

In your example you're trying to have a shell script loop that contains make variables and functions: that cannot work (how can the shell, which is a new process that make forked, ask make to re-expand some value based on a shell variable?)

When make wants to run this recipe:

```
@for i in $(notebooks); \
do \
    $(eval f=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 1))  \
    $(eval fid=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 2)) \
    echo $(f) $(fid) $(f1) ;\
done
```

it first expands all the makefile variables and functions.  Remember it's just expanding a string here, it's NOT running a shell so no shell commands are invoked.  The first two lines expand like this:

```
@for i in new:e7e45d89-94cc-4783-86c5-2236d9904a24 test:2af1d689-98c3-48f2-984d-2ea21c5135dd; \
do \
```

Then the next line is expanded:

```
    $(eval f=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 1))  \
```

Here `$i` is just a make variable `i`, which you've never set, so it's empty.  So make runs this shell command:

```
echo | cut -d: -f 1
```

which yields nothing, so `$(eval f=)` is expanded and the make variable `f` is set to the empty string.

Similarly this line:

```
    $(eval fid=$(shell echo $i | cut -d: -f 2)) \
```

sets `fid` to the empty string.

Then this line is expanded

```
    echo $(f) $(fid) $(f1) ;\
```

which expands to:

```
    echo   new ;\
```

because only `f1` has any value here.  Finally the last line:

```
done
```

So, after all that expansion, the string that is passed to the shell to be run is:

```
@for i in new:e7e45d89-94cc-4783-86c5-2236d9904a24 test:2af1d689-98c3-48f2-984d-2ea21c5135dd; \
do \
    echo   new; \
done
```

There's absolutely no point to using `$(shell ...)` *inside* the recipe; you're already in a shell so why do you need another one?  Similarly, you don't need `eval` to set make variables, you need to use shell variables.

Write your recipe like this:

```
@for i in $(notebooks); \
do \
    f=`echo $$i | cut -d: -f 1`;  \
    fid=`echo $$i | cut -d: -f 2`; \
    echo $$f $$fid $(f1) ;\
done
```

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist for the explanation.